# Typescript: Save http response for a limited amount of time

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-services

at the moment iam working on my first typescript app.

Iam struggeling somehow with my idea to save my http resonse data for 1 week. If the data is older then 1 week i want to start a new http request.

at the moment i just store my data in a variable, my code looke like this:

```
export class ExerciseData {
  data: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getExerciseList(): any {
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('https://test.test/api-exercise-v1/')
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            resolve(this.data);
          });
    });
  }
}
```

Now i want to save the data to the localstorage for 1 week.

Whats the best way to archive that?

Do i also need to touch the constructor?

**Addition:** I need to save the data to localstorage with a date and then check, if the stored data is older than 7 days. But i dont know how :(

Comment: Why don't you save the date when you make the http request, and then check `if(this.data && differenceInDays() < 7)` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, but i need to save the data to localstorage with a date and then check, if the stored data is older than 7 days. But i dont know how :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HPH48n?p=preview). In that demo, I use `localStorage` to store the list of items and also the date when those items were obtained. Please notice that since both getting and setting data in the `localStorage` returns a Promise, we need to use the `then((result) => {...})` method to work with those values.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Storage, LocalStorage } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
  }

  getExerciseList(): any {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      // Check if we have the list in the local storage
      this.local.get('ExerciseList').then((list) => {
        if(list) {
          // We have a list, so we try to find out the date
          this.local.get('ExerciseListDate').then((date) => 
          {
            if(date && this.newerThanAWeek(date)) {
              // The data is valid, so we don't do the http request
              console.log("Data retrieved from localStorage");
              resolve(JSON.parse(list));
            } else {
              // Data is old, so we make the Http request
              this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                  .map(res => res.json())
                  .subscribe(listDataFromServer => {
                    console.log("Return HTTP Request");
                    // Save this information to use it later                     
                    this.saveInfoInLocalStorage(listDataFromServer).then(() => {
                      // Data is saved now, so we can send it to the user
                      resolve(listDataFromServer);
                    });
                  });
            }
          });
        } else {
            // We don't have the list stored so we make the Http request
            this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(listDataFromServer => {
                  console.log("Return HTTP Request");
                  // Save this information to use it later                      
                  this.saveInfoInLocalStorage(listDataFromServer).then(() => {
                    // Data is saved now, so we can send it to the user
                    resolve(listDataFromServer);
                  });
                });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  public saveInfoInLocalStorage(data: Array<any>) {
    // Save the list first
    return this.local.set('ExerciseList', JSON.stringify(data)).then(() => {
      // Now we set the date
      this.local.set('ExerciseListDate', new Date());
    });
  }

  public newerThanAWeek(storedDateStr: string) {
    let today = new Date();
    let storedDate = new Date(storedDateStr);
    let timeDiff = Math.abs(today.getTime() - storedDate.getTime());
    let diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

    if(diffDays < 7) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `timeout` which will set `ExerciseData.data` to null and call it in `getExerciseList()` after `if()`.

`getExerciseList(): any {
     if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
     timeout(() => { this.data = null; }, 7*24*60*60*1000);
// ...`

To be more precise, you should add it to the Promise, when you have your data.
For example after `resolve(this.data);`

**So this is a question about cookies, not http response caching.**

If you don't know how to use cookies, use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies and set expiration time to 7 days, so when you read cookie in 7 days it will be empty and you get data from server.

Comment: Sure, but what if the user restart the app? Thats why i want to use the local storage :)

Comment: There were nothing in the request about restarting app.
If you want to save data you should use cookies and load it on the app start.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a model inside your app that contains a piece of html data plus an expiry date, and then when the data is grabbed from the http request save it local storage using `localStorage.set('key', data);` - they key could be some sort of user id if you have the ability for different users to log on to your app on the same device, or if not it could just be something that identifies this piece of data with the resource you are grabbing from your request.

So when a user then performs another request for that same data, first the localStorage is polled and the date from the data is checked against the current date - there are many ways to do this from the build in js Date class to libraries such as moment.js, and if the expiry date is still in the future, load the data with `localStorage.get('key');`. If the expiry date has passed then you know the data is now out of date and you are free to request the data through http and start the cycle again.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote an answer here it would be better for everyone involved if they gave an explanation for it - it would help people in the future coming to this question.